# MySQL my.cnf user defined global variable with set-variable

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, my.cnf

I use MySql 5.6 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I try to add a user defined global variable, that will be accessible across multiple sessions:

in `~/.my.cnf` I have:

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=2
set-variable=my_global_variable=my_string_value
```

Then I restarted MySql.

When I do `show variables`, I do not see any variable called "my_global_variable".

What might I be missing here?

Answer (score -1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/option-files.html

> Set the program variable var_name to the given value. This is
>   equivalent to --set-variable=var_name=value on the command line.
>   Spaces are permitted around the first “=” character but not around the
>   second. **This syntax is deprecated as of MySQL 4.0.** See Section
>   4.2.3.4, “[Using Options to Set Program Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/program-variables.html)”, for more information on setting program variables.

Read the [MySQl 5.6 docs about the options file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html).

Comment: I don't see anything in these links about user defined variables. Only about changing the value of predefined variables. So what is the right way to define and set a user defined global variable?

Comment: Actually, it seems like MySQL does not have a native way to define custom user defined global variables.

Comment: That's what I think, too. A way to circumvent that might be setting up some SQL that runs on every server start and uses sets some gobal variables.